# Solar panel and mppt / battery system advice

Tags: solar-energy

I got a free solar panel with specifications:

- Voc:   62.00 V
- Vmpp: 43.00 V
- Impp:  1.17 A

My question is can I hook-up a 12V / 24V mppt charger and charge a 12V battery pack with no effort?

If not, how can I approach this? I'm a bit new and need a good direction.

- [Solar panel](https://www.renugen.co.uk/gs-solar-gs-50-watt-solar-panel-module-discontinued/)
- [Mppt](https://www.victronenergy.com/solar-charge-controllers/mppt7510)
- [Battery](https://www.accu.nl/ultracell-gel-accu-12v-20ah-dcga-deep-cycle-ucg20-12?gclid=Cj0KCQjwxMjnBRCtARIsAGwWnBNMnXmesFKP4XV8TEo6NSbLWtEMZk2Xbg5YtDzznjzDqwkWAIl0eX0aAvxHEALw_wcB)

Comment: With 62V max from the panel, the first question is,  is the charge controller rated for 62V? And its data suggests that it is.  I see nothing obviously wrong here.

Comment: What do you intend to power with this system? Is there something specific, or are you just "messing around" with it to try to learn something? In general, I'd say that a 50W panel is a good match for a 240 Wh battery (will recharge in about 5-6 hours), but the average continuous load would have to be on the order of just 3-5W (will discharge in 2-3 days).

Comment: Thanks you for your comments, 240wh i want to power a shed with no electric, basic stuff like a LED lamp or a heater in winter months (interval) maybe load worktool battery.

Comment: A lamp or battery charger would be fine. But forget about getting any significant amount of heat out of a system that small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gone through the datasheets what you have provided. There is nothing wrong in the configuartion.

The MPPT controller supports up to 75V / 100V PV open circuit voltage.

Panel power is also with in the maximum range of MPPT.

The MPPT also has an auto battery select option for 12V/24V batteries.

You can hook-up all these together with out any doubt.

[Follow this article for detailed explanation and procedure](https://solarpanelsvenue.com/mppt-and-pwm-charge-controllers-in-off-grid-solar-power-systems/)

[image: Source: SOLAR PANEL SECRETS EXPOSED]